# what does ^-1 mean?

Tags: functions

Im kind of frustrated when I see the experession of (something)^-1 and its not really  clear from context that it means 1 over something or the inverse of somethings. This issue shows up frequently in textbooks of different topics, so I would like an easy method to know which one is the correct meaning.

Comment: If $x^{-1}$ it means $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: What do you mean with "1 over something"? Can you give an example of this?

Comment: If it's used on a function $f : X \to Y$, it means the inverse function $f^{-1} : Y \to X$.

Comment: It *always* means the inverse of something. When the context is multiplication, the "inverse" is the multiplicative inverse. When the context is application of a function or operator, the "inverse" is the inverse function or operator. As it happens, the multiplicative inverse of a real number $r$ is also written as $1/r$. You know that. So is it really confusing after all?

Comment: Is the use of superscript to express both inverses and exponents in trigonometric functions what is confusing you?

Comment: Please, give an example where ${ }^x$ depends on context.

Comment: @MPW If someone wrote $(x^2+2x+7)^{-1}$, it would refer to the reciprocal of the expression, which is the composition of the function with the inverse of multiplication, but isn't directly the inverse of the things involved.

Comment: @Aaron: An expression represents a number. It is not a function. So what you wrote is the multiplicative inverse of the (indeterminate) number $x^2+2x+7$. It has nothing to do with functional inverses. Right?

Comment: I will admit that there can be ambiguity in notation where an inverse function can be confused with a multiplicative inverse. I find that judicious placement of the superscript can help clear that up. For example, $f^{-1}(x)$ would be the application of the inverse function of $f$ to the argument $x$, and $f(x)^{-1}$ would be the reciprocal of the value $f(x)$. Note that neither of these can be confused with $f(x^{-1})$ which is unrelated and unambiguous. Where trig functions are involved, it can be murky, but a clarifying remark is always helpful to remove doubt. Often, context tells it all.

Comment: @MPW I like the idea of $[f(x)]^{-1}$ but what could make the inverse function clearer? $x(f)$ maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know any hard and fast rules.  Familiarity and context will trump any heuristics I can give here.  However, the best general rule of thumb I can give is that $(\text{blah})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\text{blah}}$ unless blah is an individual named function.  For example, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ refers to the inverse, and if someone wrote, "Define $f(x)=\sin(x)+x-2+x^2$ on $[0,\pi/10]$.  Then $f^{-1}(x)\ldots$ would also refer to the inverse of $f^{-1}$.

Unfortunately, there are only so many useful and concise bits of notation out there, and so they end up getting used for multiple things.  It's frustrating, but it can usually be worked around given some context.

Answer (score 0):

When applied to a number or expression, $x^{-1}$ always means $1/x$.

When applied to a function, $f^{-1}$ almost always means the inverse function. That is, the function such that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$. If reciprocals are needed, the $^{-1}$ will usually be applied elsewhere. For example, the most common interpretations of the following would be
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin^{-1}(x) &=& \arcsin(x) \\
\sin(x)^{-1} &=& \frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \csc(x) \\
\sin(x^{-1}) &=& \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
This is somewhat complicated by the unfortunate notation convention of
$$
\sin^2(x) = [\sin(x)]^2
$$
which does not conform to the above rules. Really we should be discouraging people from the notation $\sin^2$ (unless they actually mean $\sin[\sin(x)]$), but it's probably got too much inertia at this point.

Comment: Yes, you'll never see that change. The notation is classical. And don't even mention things like $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Both $x^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are inverses.

The first is the multiplicative inverse of $x$ (the number when multiplied by $x$ gives $1$).

The second is the inverse function of $f(x)$ (the function for which $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$).